# How to generate iOS IPA for Ionic app without Xcode and Mac?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ipa

My Ionic app is ready with Android platform. Now I need to generate iOS IPA for same using Windows OS or any online solution for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Ionic Package. They offer 100 builds/mo.

The docs for it are available here:
http://docs.ionic.io/services/package/#summary

If you need to send it to Itunes Connect, you can use this:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/670364#comment-1895468

Answer (score 0):

You can install mac OS in virtual machine by VMWare or other tools.

Comment: how come that did not worked ? what did you tried and what error that gave ?

Comment: Could you please let me know the steps or instruction to successfully install VMWare ?